# How to prevent Javascript from applying local timezone to Date() object?

Tags: javascript, date

Say I create a Date() object and pass in milliseconds since epoch time like so:

```
var d = new Date(0);
```

Then:

```
console.log(d);
```

Output:

```
Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

If I call `d.getHours()` the output is:

```
16
```

This is undesirable in my use case.

How can I create a date object that ignores the user's local timezone / system clock settings? I would like to be able to pass in a time in milliseconds (since epoch time) and display it as though the user were always in UTC so if they change their system clock in Windows it won't change what is displayed.

Comment: Short answer is that you can't. However you can get the users current TZ offset: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Comment: Alternatively you can specify the creation as UTC: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC However when you toString() the date it will still show the local TZ offset.

Comment: Thanks I simply subtracted the timezone offset from the original millisecond long I was passing into Date() and created a date from that and it works as intended. If you create an answer I'll checkmark it

Comment: @Joey—you don't have to subtract the offset. Doing it that way means that the built–in *toString* will append the offset and make it appear that the date is for a different time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Date.toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString):

```js
var d = new Date(0);
console.log(d.toUTCString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var now = new Date();
var utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay(), 0, 0, 0));
console.log(utcDate);
```

Comment: On 3 June 2016 at 16:35 that returns "2016-06-05T00:00:00.000Z" for me.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a date object that ignores the user's local timezone

Dates have at their heart a time value that is UTC. The host time zone is only considered when creating the time value or outputting values (getDate, getHours, etc.).

So if you want to create a Date for a specific UTC time, use UTC methods, same for output. When supplying a single numeric value to the Date constructor, it is treated as milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z so is UTC/GMT.

e.g

```js
var d = new Date(0); // zero offset from epoch

document.write(d.getUTCHours()) // 0

// toISOString uses offset +00:00
document.write('<br>' + d.toISOString()); // the ECMAScript epoch
```

If you want to format the date in a particular format using UTC values, use UTC methods, e.g.

```js
// Format Date to DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm UTC
function formatDate(d) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n;}  
  return d.getUTCFullYear() + '/' +
         z(d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '/' +
         z(d.getUTCDate()) + ' ' +
         z(d.getUTCHours()) + ':' +
         z(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ' UTC';
}

document.write(formatDate(new Date()));
```

So you can create the date using a value that is milliseconds since the epoch and then write out UTC values and everyone will see the same date and time (but make sure it's clear that the time zone is +00:00).